# Django Migration: prevent base model creation after abstract inheritance

Tags: python, django, django-1.8, python-3.2

I am creating a `BaseModel` and inheriting it in `Channel`.This `BaseModel` would have more logic while performing `save()`. I am facing an issue while migrations are completed and tables are generated.

My `api_channel` table is created with `basemodel_ptr_id` referencing to `BaseModel` table.

But, what I am looking for is to have all the fields from the `BaseModel` would be inherited into the `Channel` model. I also do not need `basemodel` table in my database.

I have gone through the official [Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance)

Please help.

**BaseModel.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class BaseModel(models.Model):
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField()

    # # To make the BaseModel abstract
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._meta.db_table = self.__class_.__name__.lower()
        super(BaseModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' On save, update_at timestamp '''
        if not self.id:
            self.created_on = timezone.now()
        self.updated_on  = timezone.now()
        return super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Channel.py**

```
from django.db import models
from api.models import base


class Channel(base.BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're setting `proxy = True` instead of `abstract = True` in the `Meta` class?

Comment: @Railslide My bad....after failing at `abstract`, I was trying every other model inheritance. That's where that `proxy` came from.

Answer (score 1):

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField()

    # # To make the BaseModel abstract
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

just use this that will solve the above problem